# How to add google vr view to webpage?

Tags: html, view, google-vr

How to insert 360 image to my website? everything i'm doing is going wrong.

i did

```
<iframe src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/embed?image=https://photos.app.goo.gl/xmYQr37QDiBT6eTN9">
</iframe>
```

i get error: 
AccessDeniedAccess denied.Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to vrview/2.0/embed.
 i did:

```
function onVrViewLoad() {
  // Selector '#vrview' finds element with id 'vrview'.
  var vrView = new VRView.Player('#foto', {
    image: 'https://photos.app.goo.gl/iVLv5RNhNchZEoZu7',
    is_stereo: true
  });
}
```

i get error :

```
Failed to load https://photos.app.goo.gl/iVLv5RNhNchZEoZu7:
```

Redirect from 'https://photos.app.goo.gl/iVLv5RNhNchZEoZu7' to 'https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMzRd9bGCldvXVeJ1Nr1t1_93yCmlOP8dmJHytoNqH5NrAF8h-hvralJTumn_sq9A?
key=RGtDaF9aMkFGN283QzZacTI0ZDAtUHJxY1hPREF3' has been blocked by CORS policy:
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://storage.googleapis.com' 
is therefore not allowed access.

I spent all day and didn't find where i am wrong...

Comment: i guess not becouse i didnt find info about that

Comment: but for google vr  view i dont need any access keys...

Comment: Ah ok, wasn't sure - whenever I have used any of google's apis I have always had to create an api key - never used the vr one though